# In SQL how do you save an array of numbers for each entry in a column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do something very simple but can't figure out how.

Say I have this table called "Tasks" where each task has a chosen set of users that should carry it out. The numbers in the Users column refer to the ID column of the "Users" table.

**Tasks table:**

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Task         | Created_On  | Users        |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Task A       | 19/11/22    | 1,3,4        |
| Task B       | 19/11/22    | 1,4,5,6      |
| Task C       | 19/11/22    | 2,3,6        |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

**Users table:**

```
+--------------+-------------+
| ID           | User        |
+--------------+-------------+
| 1            | George      |
| 2            | John        |
| 3            | Jim         |
| 4            | James       |
| 5            | Jill        |
| 6            | Joe         |
+--------------+-------------+
```

How do you create the "Users" column of the Tasks table? There's no "Array" column type in Oracle.

Comment: Do you need the concatenated Users' name instead of those numbers in the `Users` column?(eg. `George,Jim,James` instead of `1,3,4` ..etc.)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan No I just want to store the list of users associated with each task.

Comment: Can you please add the desired output as well?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan output of what?

Comment: I see two dataset from two different table, aren't they? Do you want to join them, and what fashion?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Sorry I didn't write the post correctly. Updated.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I want to create a table similar to the "Tasks" table, the problem specifically is the last column in which each row should contain a list of numbers. How do I create that column?

Comment: In SQL and ERM you use n:m relationships: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model) You need to create an intermediate table e.g. Tasks2Users.

Comment: @gekart that's so simple yet I couldn't figure it out

Comment: @User104163 Just posted an option that could help you to insert data into "bridging" table. Regards...

Comment: @dr thanks but I already figured everything out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a bridging table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE task_users (
  Task    CONSTRAINT task_users__task__fk REFERENCES tasks (task),
  User_id CONSTRAINT task_users__user_id__fk REFERENCES users (id),
  CONSTRAINT task_users__task__user_id__pk PRIMARY KEY(task, user_id)
);
```

Then you can insert the data:

```sql
INSERT INTO task_users (task, user_id)
SELECT 'Task A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Task A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Task A', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Task B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Task B', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Task B', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Task B', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Task C', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Task C', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Task C', 6 FROM DUAL;
```

and the table is constrained to only contain valid users and unique task/user pairs.

Answer (score 1):

> There's no "Array" column type in Oracle

Right, but there's another built-in datatype you could use - `sys.odcinumberlist`. Here's how:

```
SQL> create table task (task varchar2(10), created_on date, users sys.odcinumberlist);

Table created.

SQL> insert into task (task, created_on, users)
  2    values ('Task A', date '2022-11-19', sys.odcinumberlist(1,3,4));

1 row created.

SQL> select * from task;

TASK       CREATED_ON USERS
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
Task A     19.11.2022 ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 3, 4)

SQL>
```

---

So, which users are these 1, 3 and 4?

```
SQL> select * from users;

        ID USERNAME
---------- ----------
         1 George        --> this
         2 John
         3 Jim           --> this
         4 James         --> this
         5 Jill
         6 Joe

6 rows selected.

SQL> select t.task, u.username
  2  from task t join users u on u.id in (select * From table(t.users));

TASK       USERNAME
---------- ----------
Task A     George
Task A     Jim
Task A     James

SQL>
```

Comment: This does not enforce any referential constraints on the values stores in the `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` varray so you can include the value `-3.14159` when there will never be a user with a matching `id` value.

Comment: `sys.odcinumberlist` is indeed a predefined collection type, illustrating that SQL does have arrays, but I am not sure it is recommended to use it in application code. Normally we define our own using something like `create or replace type number_ntt as table of number`.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer is already accepted here is an option that could be used to insert data into bridging table from MTO's answer. SQL MODEL clause is used here:

```sql
SELECT  t.TASK, t.CREATED_ON, t.USERS, t.IDS_COUNT, t.IDX "ID_NO", t.ID, u.USER_NAME
FROM  ( Select *
        From   (    Select  TASK, CAST(0 As VarChar2(32)) "ID", USERS, CREATED_ON,
                            Coalesce(Length(USERS) - Length(Replace(USERS,',',null)), Length(USERS), 0) + 1 "IDS_COUNT"
                    From    tasks
               )
        MODEL
            PARTITION BY    (TASK)
            DIMENSION BY    (0 "IDX")
            MEASURES    (USERS, CREATED_ON, IDS_COUNT, ID)
            RULES   ITERATE(6)  -- declare bigger number than expected number of elements in list
                (
                    USERS[ITERATION_NUMBER] = USERS[0], CREATED_ON[ANY] = CREATED_ON[0], IDS_COUNT[ANY] = IDS_COUNT[0],
                    ID[ITERATION_NUMBER] = CASE 
                                              WHEN ITERATION_NUMBER BETWEEN 1 And IDS_COUNT[0] 
                                              THEN  SubStr(SubStr(',' || USERS[0] || ',', InStr(',' || USERS[0] || ',', ',', 1, ITERATION_NUMBER)+1), 1, InStr(',' || USERS[0] || ',', ',', 1, ITERATION_NUMBER+1) - InStr(',' || USERS[0] || ',', ',', 1, ITERATION_NUMBER) - 1) 
                                           END   
                )
    ) t
INNER JOIN users u ON(u.ID = t.ID)  --LEFT JOIN if you want to see possible unmatched IDs - USER_NAME would be Null
Where IDX Between 1 And IDS_COUNT
Order By  TASK, IDX
```

Result:

| TASK | CREATED_ON | USERS | IDS_COUNT | ID_NO | ID | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task A | 19-NOV-22 | 1,3,4 | 3 | 1 | 1 | George |
| Task A | 19-NOV-22 | 1,3,4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | Jim |
| Task A | 19-NOV-22 | 1,3,4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | James |
| Task B | 19-NOV-22 | 1,4,5,6 | 4 | 1 | 1 | George |
| Task B | 19-NOV-22 | 1,4,5,6 | 4 | 2 | 4 | James |
| Task B | 19-NOV-22 | 1,4,5,6 | 4 | 3 | 5 | Jill |
| Task B | 19-NOV-22 | 1,4,5,6 | 4 | 4 | 6 | Joe |
| Task C | 19-NOV-22 | 2,3,6 | 3 | 1 | 2 | John |
| Task C | 19-NOV-22 | 2,3,6 | 3 | 2 | 3 | Jim |
| Task C | 19-NOV-22 | 2,3,6 | 3 | 3 | 6 | Joe |

Regards...